# What collects data for Cacti and Cabot?

Tags: linux, monitoring, cacti

[Cacti](http://www.cacti.net/index.php) and [Cabot](http://cabotapp.com/) looks very similar and none of them says how data is collected. In Nagios it is e.g. NRPE and in [M/Monit](https://mmonit.com/) is is [Monit](https://mmonit.com/monit/).

**Question**

Which program collects the data for Cacti and Cabot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from [Cacti webpage](http://www.cacti.net/features.php)

> Data Gathering
>
> - Contains a "data input" mechanism which allows users to define custom scripts that can be used to gather data. Each script can contain arguments that must be entered for each data source created using the script (such as an IP address).
> - Built in SNMP support that can use php-snmp, ucd-snmp, or net-snmp.
> - Ability to retrieve data using SNMP or a script with an index. An example of this would be populating a list with IP interfaces or mounted partitions on a server. Integration with graph templates can be defined to enable one click graph creation for hosts.
> - A PHP-based poller is provided to execute scripts, retrieve SNMP data, and update your RRD files.

main source is internal PHP-based poller